# ParseQueryAdapter loading images really slowly?

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I'm using a ParseQueryAdapter to load images in a listview on my app but it is loading really slowly, and I've tried it on different wifis/4G and it still says the same. Is this a problems with my code or Parse itself? here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_snyps);
        ph = null;
        ctx = this;
        //p = (ParseImageView)findViewById(R.id.snyp_preview_image);
        //p.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());



        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.imageList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objs, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(e == null){
                            ph = objs.get(position);
                            file = ph.getParseFile("photo");
                            if(file != null){
                            Log.d("File name",file.getName());
                            go = true;
                            }
                            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx,ImageCloseup.class));
                        }

                    }

                });

            }



        });
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Photo> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context
            ) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Photo>() {

            @Override
            public ParseQuery<Photo> create() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ParseQuery<Photo> query = new ParseQuery<Photo>("Photo");
                query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

                return query;
            }

        });



    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Photo photo, View v, ViewGroup parent){
        if(v ==null){
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_item, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(photo, v, parent);

        ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.snyp_image);
        ParseFile file = photo.getParseFile("photo");
        if(file!=null){
            imageView.setParseFile(file);
            imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback(){

                @Override
                public void done(byte[] arg0, ParseException arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(arg1 == null){
                    Log.d("success","file got");
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

By slowly I mean, that some images will load, but the others will take
 up to a couple minutes longer to load.

Comment: You should probably show your adapter as well.  Are you forgetting to cancel tasks when your items scroll off screen?  If you don't cancel them you can build up a huge queue of tasks that will block the newer tasks that you actually care about.

Comment: I added my adapter. I'm not sure what you mean by "cancel tasks". Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: Do you have the source for ParseImageView, specifically loadInBackground()?

Comment: Not specifically. It is a built-in method that came with the Parse-1.2.1.jar.

Comment: To make any progress we need to know how the tasks that load your images are being executed.  If you don't have the source, then you'll need to file an issue formally with Parse.

Comment: I tried opening the Parse jar, but it won't let me. I know the loadInBackground() utilizes AsyncTask, but that's the only one being used in that activity so I don't know why it would be slow.

Comment: I decompiled it, it doesn't.  They use their own executor service with a threadpool that ranges between 5 and 128 threads.  It looks like ParseImageView does cancel any previous file fetch tasks when you set a new file, so my hypothesis is invalid.  It could be a similar reason though (maybe there's a bug with task cancel process).

Comment: So there's no solution?

Comment: Not with the information provided.  "Images load slow" is pretty non-descript.  What types of debugging have you tried?  Also, if you've already debugged extensively, consider contacting the Parse team.  There *may be a bug* in their source too.  Their continuation style task handling is really cool, but totally custom.  There very well could be a bug.